# Encoding.com and Amazon S3 workflow?

Tags: php, codeigniter, encoding, amazon-s3

I am creating a video website and I have codeigniter libraries that are successfully uploading the files to amazon S3 and encoding the files with encoding.com to MP4's.

My problem is that if I upload the file to S3 first, and then send to encoding.com it works perfectly but it doesn't send back to amazon S3. Would it be proper to just somehow download the encoding.com URL onto my server and then reupload it to S3 again? The url is like:

http://encoding.com.result.s3.amazonaws.com/684981684684-681684384384_53169775.mp4

I don't see anything in the encoding.com api about reuploading the finished file back to S3 or onto the host server. Is it standard practice to just use the encoding.com generated URL to show the client side files? Like using encoding.com as a CDN?

I'm just confused on the best order to do what I'm trying to accomplish. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: why not use the AWS Elastic Transcoder for this

Comment: after a little resarch i think this is what you need to look at http://www.encoding.com/api#OutputDestinations

Answer (score 0):

Probably not exactly the answer you're looking for, but this is super straight forward with zencoder.  S3 to s3 is fully supported and one of the nice, easy features about the platform.

An s3 URL looks something like:

"url": "s3://mybucket/path/file.mp4"

Works for both inputs and outputs.

Zencoder is straightforward to implement, faster, and has better features so save yourself some time and energy.

Comment: Exactly the same as encoding.com's Output Destinations pointed out by Dragon above. I definitely appreciate the response though. Thanks.

Comment: does S3 service is a requirement?